# mySQL, Image and text in one row. How to separate them?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, image, text-database

I have a blog(wordpress), and a website. I would like to connect my site to the blog. I mean that when I add a post to my blog, it(only title and image) appears on my website.
There is one problem. When i add a post with a image, it appears in one common row. I would like to separate them display only the text, or only the image of my post, but I dont know how to do that.

Here is a template of the row(I can't add a photo)

```
     [caption id="attachment_22" align="alignleft" width="300"]<a href="http://zukiemprzezswiat.pl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/20141216_112435-e1429102893578.jpg"><img class="wp-image-22 size-medium" src="http://zukiemprzezswiat.pl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/20141216_112435-300x225.jpg" alt="20141216_112435" width="300" height="225" /></a> Winowajca zamieszania :)[/caption]`

&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: left;">HERE IS SOME TEXT</p>
[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkmJ3OK8PPU[/embed]


BELOW IS THE PHP CODE, I WROTE:

    <!-- ===============================================POLACZENIE Z BAZA I ODCZYT DANYCH=============================================== -->
<?php
$connection = @mysql_connect('WEBSITE', 'LOGIN', 'PASSWORD')
or die('Brak połączenia z serwerem MySQL.<br />Błąd: '.mysql_error());

$db = @mysql_select_db('SOMETHING', $connection)
or die('Nie mogę połączyć się z bazą danych<br />Błąd: '.mysql_error());



/*######################CONNECT WITH THE TABLE wp1_posts AND DOWNLOAD ALL NEEDED DATA#############################*/    

$wynik = mysql_query("SELECT ID, post_date, post_title, post_content, FROM wp1_posts WHERE ((post_author='2') OR (post_author='1')) AND (post_status='publish')")
or die('Błąd zapytania');


if(mysql_num_rows($wynik) > 0) {
    echo "<table cellpadding=\"2\" border=1>";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$r['ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td id=\"data-my-sql\">".$r['post_date']."</a>"."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."</td>";
        echo "<td id=\"title-my-sql\"><a href=\"http://zukiemprzezswiat.pl/blog/\">".$r['post_title']."</a>"."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$r['post_content']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

To sum up, I want to separate images and text from the post_content row. At the moment it display a photo and all text.

Please, help